# SELECT AVG(invoiceamount) per debtor where date< date row

Tags: sql, group-by, subquery, average

I have a SQL table with the following columns: Invoice ID, debtor ID, invoice date and invoice amount. where invoice ID is unique.

I'm trying to create an extra column with the average invoice amount. So per row I want the average invoice amount of the debtor, but only of the invoices where the invoice date <= the invoicedate of the column.

I'm not sure where to start, all ideas are welcome

Comment: Please specify your DBMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this-

```
SELECT 
A.Invoice_ID, 
A.debtor_ID, 
A.invoice_date,
A.invoice_amount,
(
    SELECT AVG(B.invoice_amount) 
    FROM your_table B 
    WHERE B.debtor_ID = A.debtor_ID
    AND B.invoice_date <= A.invoice_date
) AS average_invoice_amount
FROM your_table A
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       avg(invoice_amount) over (partition by debtor_id order by invoice_date) as running_average
from t;
```

I *strongly* recommend this over a correlated subquery because it should be much faster -- even if you attempt to optimize the correlated subquery with indexes.